# Resolving conflicts between automated updates and manual overrides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a bit of a complex, abstract question, so forgive me if it's not specific enough.

I've encountered a specific type of problem numerous times: That on one hand, a data source is used to update a certain data structure in an automated fashion at regular intervals, but on the other hand, stakeholders want to be able to manually override the automated entries.

**Example:**

You have a list of products, which are kept up-to-date (title, description, etc.) by some automated script which uses external data sources (product databases, etc.).

Let's say that in your data source you have a toaster "Freshtoast XYZ 300" and if its name changes to "FreshToast! XYZ-300", you want to propagate that update into your own (differently structured) product model.

At the same time, if a co-worker doesn't like the name "Freshtoast XYZ 300" and wants to change it to  "Toaster XYZ 300 by Freshtoast" (manually), you don't want to override that change automatically (he would get angry), but you also don't want to simply ignore the updated name, since if the co-worker knew about the change, he'd adjust the name to "Toaster XYZ-300 by FreshToast!".

---

What's the best method to "consider" updated data sources - even for overridden data - while still allowing manual override?

PS: I'm using mostly Ruby / Rails, but I guess the question is very general. Also, to be clear, automated updates are the rule, while manual overrides are the exception in this scenario. So let's say 200,000 products get updated every single day, only 20 of which have manually overridden titles. So, for example, having to approve every single update is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes nothing...

Hands off approach: Add a string column to products table that contains a serialized list of user-touched columns. Anytime a user touches a column in the products table, put it in the serialized list. When the automatic updater hits that record it checks the list for columns it should ignore.

Hand-wringing micro-manager approach: Use a versioning library (e.g. vestal_versions gem) and add a user_id column to the products table. Anytime a user-touched record is automatically updated, send them a notification and allow them to view a before/after which they can approve or reject.

Comment: I agree that the 2 most intuitive solutions are either to "block" automated updates selectively or to have a complex "merge-like" process similar to versioning systems like Git etc. What I don't like about the former is that it's not transparent enough (sometimes I may not want to ignore an automated update); what I don't like about the latter is that it probably requires rather complex frontend and backend changes and seems a bit like overkill.

Comment: The trick is to find the right balance. You don't want to over-complicate it but users should be comfortable with their level of control.